# Custom widget with custom value in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-validation

In model I have integer field. Meaning of value of this field is "number of days since 1.1.1970", so I wanted to display it in admin interface as a date using `AdminDateWidget` to allow easier selection of date.

My only idea is to create new widget to translate integer to date:

```
class ExpireWidget(AdminDateWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if isinstance(value, (int, long)):
            value = datetime.date(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(value)
        return super(ExpireWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)
```

And following code in `admin.py`:

```
class LdapUserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'shadow_expire': ExpireWidget
            }
```

When I'm displaying it in admin date everything is ok, but before I save it I should translate date to integer. I thought that I could achieve it using `clean_field_name` function, but some validation is executed before `clean_field_name` (is it `clean()`?) and I get error that I should type integer value.

How should I translate date to int before validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each widget has method for taking data back from POST/GET and translating that data for Form validation.

It's method `def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name)`

You can see it used here: [Pseudo-form in Django admin that generates a json object on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541924/pseudo-form-in-django-admin-that-generates-a-json-object-on-save/9610446#9610446)