# Removing initial value from form

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have a form like this:

```
class StoreForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    link = forms.URLField(verify_exists=True, required=False, initial='http://')
```

When I fill out the form and leave the link field untouched, I raise an error, because `http://` is obviously not a valid link. What would be the best way to remove the initial value to get a valid form?

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the submitted values by overriding clean_foo() method for field.

```
class StoreForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    link = forms.URLField(verify_exists=True, required=False, initial='http://')

    def clean_link(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['link']
        if data == 'http://':
            return ''
        else:
            return data
```

Comment: For some reason your approach didn't work, but what I did was changing my view to this:  
  
    `if request.method == 'POST':  
        postdata = request.POST.copy()  
        if postdata['link'] == 'http://':            
            postdata['link'] = ''   
        form = AddStoreForm(postdata)  
        if form.is_valid: ...`

Answer (score 0):

Proper way of doing this I think would be extend the default widget and override `value_from_datadict` method as can be seen here:

- [Custom widget with custom value in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656680/custom-widget-with-custom-value-in-django-admin/9658880#9658880)
- [Pseudo-form in Django admin that generates a json object on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541924/pseudo-form-in-django-admin-that-generates-a-json-object-on-save/9610446#9610446)

You could also override clean() method on Field (extend URLField).

Idea would be to check if `value == initial` and return `None` in that case.

Also keep in mind that `verify_exists` has some security issues as can be seen here:
https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2011/sep/09/security-releases-issued/ (Denial of service attack via URLField)