# Combine custom model fields in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I hava a model view, which I'm accessing from django admin view.

I added some custom fields to a form and then added this form to a ModelAdmin. The user will input specific values in those fields. Then I want to get the values from the custom fields to create a python dict.

Example:

```
# models.py
class Style(models.Model):

    style_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    style_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=("Nome do Estilo"))
    style_desc = models.TextField(null=True)    
    scales = models.JSONField(encoder=None, decoder=None)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.style_id} - {str(self.style_name)}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Estilo'

# admin.py
class StyleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ca = forms.DecimalField()
    mg = forms.DecimalField()
    pH = forms.DecimalField()    
    
    class Meta:
        model = Style
        fields = '__all__'


class StyleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = StyleModelForm
    # list_display = ['style_name', 'style_desc', 'scales', 'ca', 'color']        
    fieldsets = (
        ('Dados 1', {
            'fields': ('style_name', 'style_desc', 'scales',),
        }),
        ('Section 1', {
            'fields': (('ca', 'pH', 'mg',)),
        }),
    )        
    exclude = ['style_id']
```

I would like to be able to combine fields ca, mg and pH to a python dict and then use the result to save the object to my Model Style, which has a scale JsonField.
I have tried to follow instructions from this post [Pseudo-form in Django admin that generates a json object on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541924/pseudo-form-in-django-admin-that-generates-a-json-object-on-save) , it didn't work.